# How to implement Random Search Optimization for number of principle component?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to implement Random Search Optimization for a MLPClassifier. I have successfully optimized 'hidden_layer_sizes', 'solver' and 'activation'. But I am having problem optimizing number of principle components. Since this parameter is used to create PCA to transform training dataset and is not to be passed as an argument to MLPClassifier function, I cannot pass it into the 'parameters' dictionary like other hyper parameters.

```
# PCA 
nof_prin_components = 200  # PARAMETER for optimisation in expereiments
pca = PCA(n_components=nof_prin_components, whiten=True).fit(X)
# applies PCA to the train and test images to calculate the principal components
# n_components sets the number of components to keep
X_train_pca = pca.transform(X) 

parameters = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [150,200,250,300,400],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'activation': ['relu', 'tanh', 'identity', 'logistics']
}

#Function that performs the actual hyperparameter tuning to return the best set of parameters and the best score
def tuning(clf, parameters, iterations, X, y):
  randomSearch = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=parameters, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=iterations, cv=6) 
  #n_jobs=-1 ensures that all the cores of cpu will work
  randomSearch.fit(X,y)
  params = randomSearch.best_params_
  score = randomSearch.best_score_
  return params, score

clf = MLPClassifier(batch_size=256, verbose=True, early_stopping=True)
parameters_after_tuning, score_after_tuning = tuning(clf, parameters, 20, X_train_pca, y);
print(parameters_after_tuning)
print(score_after_tuning)
```

I tried using pipelines, but have no idea how to implement it.

```
#Sklearn pipelines for number of principle components random search
pca1 = PCA(n_components=100, whiten=True).fit(X)
pca2 = PCA(n_components=200, whiten=True).fit(X)
pca3 = PCA(n_components=300, whiten=True).fit(X)
pca4 = PCA(n_components=400, whiten=True).fit(X)

estimators = [('pca 1', pca1), ('pca 2', pca2), ('pca 3', pca3), ('pca 4', pca4)]
pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
pipe[0]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most effective thing to do is to put both the `MLPClassifier` and the `PCA` into one `Pipeline` object and finetune this single pipeline. To define the parameters of the randomized search for each step of the pipeline, you just have to specify the name of the step and its parameter separated by `__` (two underscores). In your case, it would look like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('pca', PCA(whiten=True)),
    ('clf', MLPClassifier(batch_size=256, verbose=True, early_stopping=True))
])

parameters = {
    'pca__n_components': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'clf__hidden_layer_sizes': [150, 200, 250, 300, 400],
    'clf__solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'clf__activation': ['relu', 'tanh', 'identity', 'logistics']
}
```

When passed to `RandomizedSearchCV`, the whole pipeline will be finetuned and therefore return the best parameters for both the `PCA` and `MLPClassifier`.

```
parameters_after_tuning, score_after_tuning = tuning(pipeline, parameters, 20, X, y)
```

Observe that you no longer have to pass the transformed dataset `X_train_pca` to `RandomizedSearchCV` but `X` instead, since the transformation is now part of the pipeline.

For more information about how to use `Pipeline` refer to its [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and the [User guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline).

Comment: How can I access a pca and clf  in the functions after passing the pipeline as a argument?

Comment: `Pipeline` objects are subscriptable just like lists. That means you can use `pipeline[0]` to access the object at the first step (`PCA`) and `pipeline[1]` to access the object at the second step (`MLPClassifier`). This and other methods are mentioned in the user guide for which I provided the link in the answer. Please have a look there as well.

Comment: I cannot figure after passing the pipeline, how to implement RandomizedSearchCV for pca inside the "tuning" function. I tried implementing it by calling RandomizedSearchCV funciton again for pca by passing 'nof_prin-components' as  parameter. But I couldn't seem to make it work. Any help?